# creating a std::vector of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I currently have a class that uses template arguments. I need an array of these. How could I do this (without boost).
ex:

```
template <typename RET, typename T>
class AguiTimedEvent {
    RET (*onEvent)(T arg);
    double timeStamp;
public:
    RET call(T arg);
    bool expired();
    AguiTimedEvent();
    AguiTimedEvent(RET (*Timefunc)(T arg), double timeSec);
};
```

and I would need to something like:

```
AguiTimedEvent t<int, int>(func, 5.0);
v.push_back(t);
...
v[0].call();
```

I don't actually need the return value, but I just have it to make it more flexible. If the return value causes an issue I could limit it to void functions, but defiantly the arg needs to be templated. What can I do? Thanks

*I need the vector to handle any type, I need an array, where the array can dispatch events of X Y, not just int int

Comment: I suspect you meant to also specify you don't care about the return type *so the vector should handle events of different return types*?

Comment: @GMan yes, and of arbitrary argument types too

Comment: You're really looking into re-inventing Boost.Function, Boost.Bind and/or Boost.Signals. Your best bet is to either use them, or look at it and re-write it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<AguiTimedEvent<int, int> > v;
```

If you need to store objects of different `AguiTimedEvent` types that have different template arguments, you need to create a base class (e.g., `AguiTimedEventBase`) and store pointers in the `vector`.

Comment: Note the extra space between "> >", otherwise your compiler won't read it right.

Comment: Grumble, +1 but I'm only boosting you higher on the top user list than me. >:(. I need to pass you. :)

Comment: @GMan:  Ha ha.  Well, good news for your position on the all-time list:  now that C++ isn't really my most frequently used language anymore, I anticipate my participation in [c++] decreasing (just as soon as I stop banging my head on my desk wondering why C# can't be just a little more like C++ :-D).

Comment: I'm not sure how the base class idea would achieve this?

Comment: @Milo:  It sounds like you are looking for something exactly like what [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/function.html) provides (your standard library implementation may also provide `function`).  Basically, you have the derived class type store the function pointer and you call that function through a virtual function declared in the base class.

Comment: @James McNellis so there is no way to do this using only the c++ 98 or c++ 03 standard?

Comment: @Milo:  The Boost.Function library should work on any relatively standards-compliant C++ compiler (C++03).

Comment: @Milo: Boost isn't magic, it's still written in C++. You can open it up and attempt to re-write it yourself. I really suggest you adopt Boost, though.

Comment: @Milo:  Looking at your recent questions, I'd say you'd benefit from using quite a few of the Boost libraries.  As GMan said, it's all open source; you can easily download the Boost source and see how the polymorphic function wrappers are implemented (though, with all the compatibility support in Boost code, it may be quite an adventure).  You can implement your own polymorphic function wrapper if you want:  it's just a simple matter of programming.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't face a problem with the following code:

```
template <typename RET, typename T>
class AguiTimedEvent {
    RET (*onEvent)(T arg);
    double timeStamp;
public:
    RET call(T arg) {return 0;}
    bool expired() {}
    AguiTimedEvent() {}
    AguiTimedEvent(RET (*Timefunc)(T arg), double timeSec) {}
};

int func(int x) {return 0;}

int main()
{
    vector< AguiTimedEvent<int, int> > v;
    AguiTimedEvent<int, int> t(func, 5.0);

    v.push_back(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But what if its not int int, i need the vector to handle any type

Comment: @Milo, do you mean a singe vector should contain multiple types? i don't think that's possible.

Comment: @Donotalo What would be a way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Donotalo Polymorphism is not really that useful for this since a derived class has to be created for each arg type

Comment: @Milo:  That's exactly why polymorphism _is_ useful:  you have many derived classes that all have the same behavior.

Comment: yea but a derived class for each argument is quite a bit, it feels like templates should be able to help for this, ex, creates the derived class at runtime based on template args

Comment: @Milo:  C++ is statically typed; you can't create types at runtime.