# Class member: Vector of templatized class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that has a member that is a vector of another class that is templatized.

My code in classA.h looks like this:

```
template <typename T> vector<classB<T> >
```

I get errors such as "no appropriate default constructor is available"
and "multiple template parameter lists are not allowed."
I previously had no errors in classB until I added this line to classA.

I don't have a lot of experience using templates and don't know why it isn't compiling, or what exactly the syntax should be. 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929398/creating-a-stdvector-of-a-templated-class) seems to help but the answer is too terse for me to understand fully. Is it really necessary to make a base class and derive from it as that answer suggests? Does class A need to be templatized as well since it has this vector member?

What's going on?

any help is much appreciated

Comment: This needs more context. Please show the definition of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually declaring a template in the specified snipped. If that's a member of a class the class must be a template and propagate the type information in the member, something like

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
     vector<MyClass<T>> _vector;
}
```

Comment: oh, this is a problem. This is a Qt project and
ClassA is a member of the MainWindow class. 
But then if ClassA must be templatized, then so does MainWindow - but Class A and its member, a vector of classB's get their type from user input, after the user enters some parameters and clicks a button to create these objects.

It looks like I should either drop the templatization or redesign the class relationships.